# Double split in SSRS/SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am a total newbie to SQL expressions and am always learning.

I want to double split a string using an expression in SQL Server Reporting Services report builder.

I basically have a load of computers in different AD OUs and am pulling the AD OU back into the report in the distringuished name format so it is

> OU=12345,OU=OUNAME,OU=OUNAME2,DC=domain,DC=local

as an example. I want to be left with just one specific portion of the string.

I already have something like this...

```sql
=(Split(Fields!AD_Location.Value, "=")).GetValue(2))
```

But the outcome is something like "OUNAME,OU" when i just want "OUNAME" so can the result on the first split be split again using "," as the delimiter?

I was thinking just doing another split but what do i put as the input? Can the first split be stored in a variable in the expression and then used in the second split? Any help much appreciated.

```sql
=Split(=(Split(Fields!AD_Location.Value, "=")).GetValue(2), ",").GetValue(0)
```

I tried the above but it doesn't seem to want to let me save the report to test it so there must be a parse error.

Comment: remove the second `=` ? `=Split((Split( ...`

Comment: Can you post the input and the desired output?

Comment: split on the "," first then "=", something like: 
    =(split((Split(Fields!AD_Location.Value,",")).getvalue(1),"=")).getvalue(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can get rid of the "OU=" using `Replace` giving us a comma delimited string, then split on "," and get the second value to return "OUNAME":

```
=Split(Replace(Fields!AD_Location, "OU=", ""), ",").GetValue(1)
```

I assume we are only interested in extracting the second value from this string and we can ignore the "DC=" portion but if that is important to you you can nest a second `Replace` to remove that prefix as well.